# Can I connect to SQL Server from a UWP app?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sql-server

I'd like to connect to a SQL Server directly from Windows Mobile, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few apps in the Store that claim to have the ability to connect to and manage SQL Server databases. I haven't actually tried them myself, though, so use them at your own risk:

- [SQL Server Management](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/sql-server-management/9nblggh520dw)
- [SQL Client Metro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/sql-client-metro/9nblggh4vtvb)
- [SQLManagerPlus](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/sqlmanagerplus/9nblggh1p5df)

Based on the screenshots, the first two look like differently skinned versions of the same app. The developer is also the same, so I'm not sure why one costs more.

The last one is free, but the permissions list looks a bit suspicious - a database client shouldn't need to access your phone's location, sensors or media.

If I were you, I'd rather look into installing a web-based management interface on the SQL Server and accessing that from my phone (but I realise of course that this might not always be an option).